# how to change screen to a screen with kivymd bottomnavigation

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, bottomnavigationview, kivymd, android-bottomnav

I added KivyMD BottomNavigation to my App, I am able to switch screens with icon, but the issue is switching back to a screen containing the BottomNavigation
(let's say we in any of the screens containing Toolbar and BottomNavigation, we use the toolbar to switch to a entirely different screen, I am unable to go back to the previous screen or even navigate to any of thr screens containing the bottomnavigation and toolbar, it returns a blank white screen).

Despite naming the screen, so my question is; 1. am I refering (naming) the BottomNavigationItem wrongly, if yes please what should I change. (2) is there something am missing, please let me know.

Thank you.

here's my main.py file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.size = (300, 530)


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class IntroScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WaysScreen(Screen):
    pass


class To_DoScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SuccessScreen(Screen):
    pass


class GoalsScreen(Screen):
    pass


class BellaBaron(Screen):
    pass


class SearchScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class CalendarScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ExtraScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ArchiveScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Contact_InfoScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TenThousandApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Green'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = '200'
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        self.sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(IntroScreen(name="intro_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(WaysScreen(name="ways_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(To_DoScreen(name="to_do_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(SuccessScreen(name="success_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(GoalsScreen(name="goals_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(BellaBaron(name="bella_baron"))
        self.sm.add_widget(SearchScreen(name="search_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name="menu_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(CalendarScreen(name="calendar_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(ExtraScreen(name="extra_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(ArchiveScreen(name="archive_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Contact_InfoScreen(name="contact_info_screen"))

        return self.sm

    def change_screen(self, screen):
        self.sm.current = screen


TenThousandApp().run()
```

and here's my .kv file

```
# ScreenManager:

#start of imagelist
<MyTile@SmartTileWithLabel>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "240dp"

<MainScreen>:

    MDBottomNavigation:
        # panel_color: .2, .2, .2, 1

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "intro_screen"
            text: 'home'
            icon: 'home'

            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                # md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_dark

                MDToolbar:
                    id: intro_screen_toolbar
                    title: '[font=Gabriola][size=40][color=#FD0101]First[/color][/size][size=28]project[/size][/font]'
                    right_action_items: [["calendar-month", lambda x: app.change_screen('to_do_screen')]] #links to to-do listss screen
                    elevation: "8dp"

                MDCard:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: 16
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "360dp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
                    height: root.height - intro_screen_toolbar.height - dp(55)
                    y: root.height - intro_screen_toolbar.height - dp(50)
                    elevation: "8dp"
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    radius: 15

                    ScrollView:
                        MDLabel:
                            markup: True
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size: self.texture_size
                            text:
                                """[b][i]“Your time is limited, so don’t waste it living someone else’s life. Don’t be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people’s thinking. Don’t let the noise of other’s opinions drown out your own inner voice. And most important, have the courage to follow your heart and intuition. They somehow already know what you truly want to become. Everything else is secondary.”[/i][/b]
                                – Steve Jobs"""

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "success_screen"
            text: 'home'
            icon: 'account-group'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                MDToolbar:
                    id: success_screen_toolbar
                    title: "Success Stories"
                    right_action_items: [["progress-clock", lambda x: app.change_screen('goals_screen')]] #links to goals and how screen
                    elevation: "8dp"

                ScrollView:
                    MDGridLayout:
                        cols: 1
                        adaptive_height: True
                        padding: dp(4), dp(4)
                        spacing: dp(4)

                        MyTile:
                            source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"
                            text: "[size=26]Cat 1[/size]\\n[size=14]cat-1.jpg[/size]"

                            on_release:
                                app.root.current = 'bella_baron'

                        MyTile:
                            source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"
                            text: "[size=26]Cat 2[/size]\\n[size=14]cat-2.jpg[/size]"
                            tile_text_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color

                        MyTile:
                            source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"
                            text: "[size=26][color=#ffffff]Cat 3[/color][/size]\\n[size=14]cat-3.jpg[/size]"
                            tile_text_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color


        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "search_screen"
            text: 'search'
            icon: 'magnify'

            FloatLayout:
                MDTextField:
                    mode: 'fill'
                    hint_text: "Search"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .9}
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: 280

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "menu_screen"
            text: 'menu'
            icon: 'menu'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                md_bg_color: (240/255, 240/255, 240/255, 1)

                MDToolbar:
                    id: menu_screen_toolbar
                    title: "Tools"
                    elevation: "8dp"

                MDCard:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: 16
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "360dp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
                    height: root.height - menu_screen_toolbar.height - dp(55)
                    y: root.height - menu_screen_toolbar.height - dp(50)
                    elevation: 8
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    radius: 15

                    ScrollView:
                        MDList:
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "Calendar"
                                on_release:
                                    app.root.current = "calendar_screen"
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "calendar-month"
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "Extra"
                                on_release:
                                    app.root.current = "extra_screen" 
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "notebook-multiple"
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "Archive"
                                on_release:
                                    app.root.current = "archive_screen"
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "archive"
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "contact Us"
                                on_release:
                                    app.root.current = "contact_info_screen"
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "email-mark-as-unread"



<WaysScreen>
    name: "ways_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: ways_screen_toolbar
            title: "How-tos"
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('intro_screen')]] # to add more list
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('intro_screen')]]
            elevation: "8dp"

        ScrollView:

            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                adaptive_height: True
                spacing: 10
                padding: 10

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    Image:
                        source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello dear'

                    ScrollView:
                        MDLabel:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size: self.texture_size
                            # halign: 'center'
                            text:
                                """This screens contains a MDcard which where the image is placed, and a MDLabel and neccessary widgets used to tell the success story, under the MDCard."""
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello boss'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello goodness'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello hi'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello yes?'

<To_DoScreen>
    name: "to_do_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: to_do_screen_toolbar
            title: 'To-Do-List'
            right_action_items: [['plus', lambda x: x]] # to add more list
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('intro_screen')]]
            elevation: "8dp"

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            elevation: 8
            radius: 15
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '280', '360'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - to_do_screen_toolbar.height + dp(10)
            y: root.height - to_do_screen_toolbar.height - dp(20)


<GoalsScreen>
    name: 'goals_screen'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: goals_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Goals'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('success_screen')]]
            elevation: "8dp"

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "280dp", "360dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - goals_screen_toolbar.height + dp(10)
            y: root.height - goals_screen_toolbar.height - dp(20)
            elevation: "8dp"
            orientation: 'vertical'
            radius: 15

<BellaBaron>
    name: 'bella_baron'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        md_bg_color: (240/255, 240/255, 240/255, 1)

        MDToolbar:
            id: bella_baron_toolbar
            title: "Bella Baron"
            left_action_items: [["keyboard-backspace", lambda x: app.change_screen('success_screen')]]
            right_action_items: [["progress-check", lambda x: app.change_screen('goals_screen')]] #link to progress screen
            elevation: "8dp"

        ScrollView:

            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                adaptive_height: True
                spacing: 10
                padding: 10

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    Image:
                        source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello dear'

                    ScrollView:
                        MDLabel:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size: self.texture_size
                            # halign: 'center'
                            text:
                                """This screens contains a MDcard which where the image is placed, and a MDLabel and neccessary widgets used to tell the success story, under the MDCard."""
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello boss'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello goodness'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello hi'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello yes?'


<CalendarScreen>
    name: "calendar_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: calendar_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Calendar'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('menu_screen')]]
            right_action_items: [['calendar', lambda x: x]] # on press returns today's date
            elevation: "8dp"

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            elevation: 8
            radius: 15
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '280', '360'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - calendar_screen_toolbar.height + dp(10)
            y: root.height - calendar_screen_toolbar.height - dp(20)

# I will remove this screen if there is no need for it.
<ExtraScreen>
    name: "extra_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: extra_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Extra'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('menu_screen')]]
            elevation: "8dp"

        ScrollView:

            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                adaptive_height: True
                spacing: 10
                padding: 10

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    Image:
                        source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello dear'

                    ScrollView:
                        MDLabel:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size: self.texture_size
                            # halign: 'center'
                            text:
                                """This screens contains a MDcard which where the image is placed, and a MDLabel and neccessary widgets used to tell the success story, under the MDCard."""
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello boss'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello goodness'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello hi'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello yes?'

<ArchiveScreen>
    name: "archive_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: archive_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Archive'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('menu_screen')]]
            elevation: "8dp"

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            elevation: 8
            radius: 15
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '280', '360'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - archive_screen_toolbar.height + dp(10)
            y: root.height - archive_screen_toolbar.height - dp(20)

<Contact_InfoScreen>
    name: "contact_info_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: contact_info_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Contact Info'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('menu_screen')]]
            elevation: "8dp"

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            elevation: 8
            radius: 15
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '280', '360'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - contact_info_screen_toolbar.height + dp(10)
            y: root.height - contact_info_screen_toolbar.height - dp(20)

            ScrollView:
                MDLabel:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    size: self.texture_size
                    text:
                        """feel free to reach us @"""
```

Comment: I don't see a `<MenuScreen>` rule in your `kv`, so that `Screen` will be empty.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yes I had to remove it, so I could add BottomNavigation. Although I named a BottomNavigationItem similarly. Please John I would appreciate if you could write a sample code of how it should look like. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your question. If you do not want to see an empty screen, then don't switch the current screen to an empty screen. The line: `left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('menu_screen')]]` in your `kv` will switch to the empty `MenuScreen`. Try switching to a non-empty screen, like: `left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('main_screen')]]`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I really appreciate you taking the time to look at my code... I understand what you are saying (that I can't switch to menu_screen, as I didn't create a <MenuScreen> class in my .kv file), but I recently learnt that MDBottomNavigation is a like a screen manager, and MDBottomNavigationItem is like a screen. in my .kv file, there are 4 MDBottomNavigationItem, which I have named, and I thought it would function like a normal screen (that can be called like I did in my code above)... my question is how do I refer back to these screens (MDBottomNavigationItem) from a another screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change to a different `MDBottomNavigationItem` in a `MDBottomNavigation`, you should use the `switch_tab()` method of `MDBottomNavigation`. You can add a method to your `TenThousandApp` class:

```
def change_screen_item(self, nav_item):
    # change to the MainScreen and switch to the spcified MDBottomNavigationItem
    s = self.sm.get_screen('main_screen')
    s.ids.bottom_nav.switch_tab(nav_item)
    self.sm.current = 'main_screen'
```

In your `kv`, you must add an `id` for the `MDBottomNavigation`:

```
<MainScreen>:

    MDBottomNavigation:
        id: bottom_nav
        # panel_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
```

That `id` is used to access the `MDBottomNavigation` instance.

Then in the `kv`, you can use the `change_screen_item()` to switch to the `MainScreen` and switch to the specified `MDBottomNavigationItem`, like this:

```
<CalendarScreen>
    name: "calendar_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: calendar_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Calendar'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen_item('intro_screen')]]
            right_action_items: [['calendar', lambda x: x]] # on press returns today's date
            elevation: "8dp"
```

The above code will switch to the `intro_screen` item of the `MainScreen`.

Comment: John, I really don't know how to thank you.. It works it magic!!! Thank you for taking the time to look at my code, I really appreciate it, THANK YOU John..